# Stripe API PHP - Retreive Subscription (Without Knowing Subscription ID)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

How does one retrieve a customer's subscription(s) using the Stripe PHP library when the subscription IDs are not already known?

Is there a way to do something like:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customerId);

$subscription = $customer->subscription;
```

And the value in $subscription will hold the customer's subscription information.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to list the subscriptions, passing a customer id.

```
\Stripe\Subscription::all(array('customer'=>$customerId,'limit'=>10));
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#list_subscriptions